# Where can I find the mongoDB database

Tags: macos, mongodb, meteor

i install the meteor package and within is the mongoDB. Now I made an easy application and create a mongo db collection ...

Todos = new Mongo.Collection('todos');

I write data in this collection and everything works fine. BUT! I can not find the mongodb and the collections an my Mac?! I read on some sites that I have to watch at /data/db but on my mac there is not such a file...

Can anyone explain where mongoDb takes the data on my Mac.
Thank you

Comment: Checkout: [http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Mongo](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Mongo) also as this article mentions:  `Meteor by default creates local mongodb database (projectname/.meteor/local/db)` [http://meteor.hromnik.com/blog/meteor-run-without-creating-local-mongo-database](http://meteor.hromnik.com/blog/meteor-run-without-creating-local-mongo-database)

Answer (score 1):

Countless duplicates to this one if you use the search engine, but a short answer would be to look inside: `.meteor/local/db`

Comment: @Kyll true about the flags but I tend not to post links to external resources, although I think that's not a bad practice at all.

Comment: I don't remember saying I found a "*duplicate question*" on stackoverflow; I posted the references to the external content. Flag this if you find a duplicate question.